# One server hosted locally on 2 Wi-Fi networks

Tags: networking

I have a Minecraft server, and I’m setting it up for my local arcade. I want people who come in to connect to it (their public Wi-Fi) and the consoles they have to connect to it (private network). It’s one router, but I don’t know how to make the server go across both? Please let me know if this is possible. (I thought about port forwarding but I don’t want to convince them to do that.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the server two Ethernet ports and connect one to the private LAN and the other to the public LAN.

Or, you could make sure its one NIC is VLAN capable, plug it into a VLAN-capable managed switch, set that switch port as a trunk port with both the public and private VLANs available so the server can be connected to both LANs via the magic of VLAN tagging.

Comment: 2 questions: its 1 router, that gives off 2 networks. Or at least that's what the owners told me. Would there be an Ethernet port for each network? Or would I need to configure it? Lastly, would i just buy one of those PCIE cards with 2 Ethernet ports at the end?

Comment: Nevermind I just fully read that and realized I don't need to ask that question. Thank you very much for your help. I'll go ahead and mark you as the answer.